# Propositional logic: Simplify p -> (q -> r)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My approach is to first get rid of the if-thens.

`p -> (q -> r)`

`p -> (~q v r)` by Implication law

`~p v (~q v r)` by implication law

`(~p v ~q) v r` by Associative law

`~(q & p) v r` by Demorgan's law

Is my approach correct?

Comment: If you consider that 'simpler', sure!

Comment: Having said that, in what sense the result is "simpler" ? The original formula has two connectives; the last one has three.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, i have a mistake for the assoc step

Answer (score 1):

I think you could conclude that $p\wedge q\rightarrow r$

Comment: I see, and that is by doing implication law again on ~(q & p) v r